# how to print url from html code in php when url contain spaces

Tags: php, url

See i have an url in a html code

```
<a href="http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">play</a>
```

Now i want to print this url as it is written in a php page

```
http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3
```

You can see that between the url **05 Dabangg Reloaded** their is space. I made this program to print url from this html code..

```
$str = "<a href="http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">play</a>";

$pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i';
if (preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$matches))


foreach($matches[1] as $data)
{
$str=$data;
echo $str; 
}
```

Then i am getting this

```
http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05
```

please do not mention on foreach($matches[1] as $data) line bcoz i am using it with so many urls.. I just want to know how to print the whole url in this format.

```
http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3
```

Spaces are become a huge matter.. Do not know how to fix it..
What i need to add inside

```
$pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i';
```

For making it completely workable.
Please suggest me any idea.

Comment: Filenames in URL need prepare using urlencode()

Comment: It's illegal for URLs to have spaces in them. Encode the spaces as `%20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can str_replace each one -space- with `%20` for encoding your URL

```
<?php
 $url_org = 'http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3';
 $url_edited = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url_org);
?>
 <a href="<?php echo $url_edited; ?>" target="_blank"> HERE </a>
```

This will work.

Comment: I am using $pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i'; this code for getting url from html but due to " " spaces i am not getting the complete url..This is my problem.. I think str_replace can not give me complete url from the html code. I need something by which i can get the complete url inside $str; ..

Comment: Apply the string replace function on the `href="http://b48.ve...` first and then excute the preg_match, you need to get rid of spaces before the preg.

Comment: I did that man but nothing happened. $str = "<a href="http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">play</a>";
 $str1 = $string;
str = str_replace(' ', '%20', $str1); 

$pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i';
if (preg_match_all($pattern,$str1,$matches))


foreach($matches[1] as $data)
   {

  $str1=$data;
  echo $str1;
  }


} but nothing happened

Comment: @elavarasan lee The only one thing he needs to take in considration when excuting your or his code is that the `href` attribute MUST BE the first attribute in the anchor, like if it was `<a id="smth" href="http://etc.."` it won't work, same thing can be said for his pattern matching

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '<a href="http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">play</a>';
$arr = explode("\"", $str);
$pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i';
$url = preg_grep($pattern,$arr);
$url = implode('',$url);
Output: $url = 'http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3'
```

---

**Update:** 2nd Solution [Reference-[DOMElement]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php).

```
$str = '<a href="http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">play</a>';
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);
$search_item = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($search_item as $search_item) {
    $url = $search_item->getAttribute('href');
}
echo $url; //Output: http://b48.ve.vc/b/data/48/3746/05 Dabangg Reloaded_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3
```

Comment: I am using $pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i'; this code for getting url from html but due to " " spaces i am not getting the complete url..This is my problem.. I think str_replace can not give me complete url from the html code. I need something by which i can get the complete url inside $str; ..

Comment: I am telling that you can drink your soup using a spoon. But you are being adamant that you want to drink it with **FORK**!!! Why to complicate this when there's a predefined function for it...!!!

Comment: Man i know that but try to understand that i have url with some HTML code and so i need to remove all the HTML code for that i am using $pattern = ... this code is helping for getting rid of from all the HTML code. But this code is not printing complete url it just stop when it got empty space between the url

Comment: @Kapil: U should consider JEES comment before accepting my answer: "The only one thing he needs to take in considration when excuting your or his code is that the href attribute MUST BE the first attribute in the anchor, like if it was `<a id="smth" href="http://etc.."` it won't work, same thing can be said for his pattern matching"

Comment: I also got it solved. I have used a very similar trick like you. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @Kapil: Welcome. I found one more solution. I found it interesting to know, so I updated that also here.